# Communicating with Systemd service through socket mapped to stdin

Tags: bash, sockets, systemd

I'm creating my first background service and I want to communicate with it through a socket.

I have the following script `/tmp/myservice.sh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

while read received_cmd
do
    echo "Received command ${received_cmd}"
done
```

And the following socket `/etc/systemd/user/myservice.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=Socket to communicate with myservice

[Socket]
ListenSequentialPacket=/tmp/myservice.socket
```

And the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=A simple service example

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /tmp/myservice.sh
StandardError=journal
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
Type=simple
```

The idea is to understand how to communicate with a background service, here using an unix file socket. The script works well when launched from the shell and reading stdin and I thought that by setting `StandardInput = "socket"` it would read from the socket the same way.

Nevertheless, when I run `nc -U /tmp/myservice.socket` the command returns right away and I have the following output:

```
$ journalctl --user -u myservice
-- Logs begin at Sat 2020-10-24 17:26:25 BST, end at Thu 2020-10-29 14:00:53 GMT. --
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: Started A simple service example.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny bash[21941]: /tmp/myservice.sh: line 3: read: read error: 0: Invalid argument
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: myservice.service: Succeeded.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: Started A simple service example.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny bash[21942]: /tmp/myservice.sh: line 3: read: read error: 0: Invalid argument
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: myservice.service: Succeeded.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: Started A simple service example.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny bash[21943]: /tmp/myservice.sh: line 3: read: read error: 0: Invalid argument
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: myservice.service: Succeeded.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: Started A simple service example.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny bash[21944]: /tmp/myservice.sh: line 3: read: read error: 0: Invalid argument
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: myservice.service: Succeeded.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: Started A simple service example.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny bash[21945]: /tmp/myservice.sh: line 3: read: read error: 0: Invalid argument
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: myservice.service: Succeeded.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: myservice.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: myservice.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Oct 29 08:40:16 shiny systemd[1689]: Failed to start A simple service example.
```

Did I misunderstand how sockets work? Why `read` fails to read from the socket? Should I use another mechanism to communicate with my background service (as I said, it's my first background service so I may do unconventional things here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I have seen working with a shell script is `ListenStream=` rather than `ListenSequentialPacket=`. (Obviously, this means you lose packet boundaries, but the shell read is usually oriented to read lines ending `\n` from streams, so it is not usually a problem).

But the most important thing that is missing, is the extra `Accept` line:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=...
Accept=true
```

As I understand it, without this the service will be passed a socket on which it must first do a socket `accept()` call, to get the actual connection socket (hence the `read` error). The service must also then handle all further connections.

By using `Accept=true`, a new service will be started for each new connection, and will be passed the immediately usable socket. Note, however, that this means the service must now be templated, i.e. called `myservice@.service` rather than `myservice.service`.

(For datagram sockets, `Accept` must be left defaulted to false). See `man systemd.socket`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I don't want to start a new service on each connection (let's say that myservice manages a state that I don't want to reset) is there a way to achieve the same thing as with "accept" but without spawning a new service every time a client connect to the socket?

Comment: There's a new systemd utility `systemd-socket-proxyd` that can do the accept for you, but I'm not sure how to use it. It has examples in its man page. Perhaps instead of a socket you could just use a fifo, `ListenFIFO`, but I don't know much about that either at the moment.